# Listing scheduled notifications in a table view controller

Tags: ios, xcode, uitableview, swift3

I am trying to list all the notifications a user has created and scheduled in my app, similar to that of the list of alarms in the 'Clock' app from apple. However, each time I get the array of notifications and attempt to display them, they are not being correctly displayed all the time.

Each notification is repeated each day at the same time, so I am using `UNUserNotificationCenter.current().getPendingNotificationRequests` to get an array of the notifications. With this array of notifications, I iterate over each notification, create a new custom 'Reminder' object and add it to my array of 'Reminders' which I use when I display the notifications in the table view controller.

I do this every time using the viewWillAppear function.

Here is the code:

```
override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(animated)

    generateReminders()

    tableView.reloadData()
}

func generateReminders()
{
    let center = UNUserNotificationCenter.current()
    center.getPendingNotificationRequests { (notifications) in
        for item in notifications {
            if let trigger = item.trigger as? UNCalendarNotificationTrigger,
                let triggerDate = trigger.nextTriggerDate() {
                var withSound = true
                if(item.content.sound != UNNotificationSound.default)
                {
                    withSound = false
                }
                self.reminders.append(Reminder(identifier: item.identifier, time: triggerDate, message: item.content.body, withSound: withSound, isAPendingNotification: true))
            }
        }
        self.remindersCount = notifications.count
    }
}
```

When the cells are about to be displayed in the table view controller, I use the 'Reminder' array to customise each cell to display the information of the notification. This is all done in the 'cellForRowAt' function, code below.

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "Reminder", for: indexPath)
    var text = ""
    var detailText = ""

    if(indexPath.row < remindersCount) {
        let reminder = reminders[indexPath.row]
        let formatter = DateFormatter()
        formatter.dateFormat = "HH:mm"

        text = formatter.string(from: reminder.Time)
        detailText = reminder.Message
    }

    cell.textLabel?.text = text
    cell.detailTextLabel?.text = detailText

    return cell
}
```

When a user selects another tab to view, I reset the 'reminders' object to be empty so that when they return to this tab, an updated array of notifications is displayed, code below.

```
override func viewWillDisappear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillDisappear(animated)
    reminders = [Reminder]()
    remindersCount = 0
    tableView.setNeedsDisplay()
}
```

The issue I am facing is this is extremely inconsistent, sometimes all the notifications are displayed, sometimes only some are displayed and other times none of them are displayed. However, each time I print out the count of the number of notifications in the `UNUserNotificationCenter.current().getPendingNotificationRequests` method it is always the correct number. Furthermore, whenever I click on a cell that should contain information about a notification,  the information is there, it is just not being displayed.

Here is a short video of these issues.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/nMVX4.jpg

I am unsure how to fix this, I have attempted to run the code on the main queue and on the global queue with the quality of service set to '.userInteractive' as shown below, but, still no dice.

```
let center = UNUserNotificationCenter.current()
    let dq = DispatchQueue.global(qos: .userInteractive)
    dq.async {
        center.getPendingNotificationRequests { (notifications) in
            for item in notifications {
                if let trigger = item.trigger as? UNCalendarNotificationTrigger,
                    let triggerDate = trigger.nextTriggerDate() {
                    var withSound = true
                    if(item.content.sound != UNNotificationSound.default)
                    {
                        withSound = false
                    }
                    self.reminders.append(Reminder(identifier: item.identifier, time: triggerDate, message: item.content.body, withSound: withSound, isAPendingNotification: true))
                }
            }
            self.remindersCount = notifications.count
        }
    }
```

A small application of this issue occurring can be downloaded from this Github repository.

https://github.com/AlexMarchant98/LitstingNotificationsIssue

Comment: did you check my answer ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are some issues in your code of `tableview` as listed below.

1. You used static cells in your tableview which is not the proper way if you have dynamic rows.

**Suggestion** : Use **Dynamic Prototype Cell** for your `tableview`.

2. `remindersCount` not required at all as its already there in your array count.

**Suggestion** : Use `self.reminders.count` for array count.

3. `unwindToRemindersTableViewController()` method have `generateReminders()` call which is not required as `viewWillAppear()` will call when view dismiss.

**Suggestion** : Check **ViewController** life cycle you will get proper idea how to reload data.

I have updated some code in your sample project.

Please find updated code [here](https://github.com/dhaneshgosai/LitstingNotificationsIssue).

[Github updated demo](https://github.com/dhaneshgosai/LitstingNotificationsIssue)

Hope this will helps!

Answer (score 0):

The problem with your code is the timing when `tableView.reloadData()` gets executed.

`UNUserNotificationCenter.current().getPendingNotificationRequests()` is a asynchronous call and therefore the `reminders` array gets filled *after* `tableView.reloadData()` was called.

Moving `tableView.reloadData()` to the end of the callback-block of `getPendingNotificationRequests()` should fix your issue. (And don't forget to trigger the `reloadData()` from the main thread)

```
func generateReminders()
{
    let center = UNUserNotificationCenter.current()
    let dq = DispatchQueue.global(qos: .userInteractive)
    dq.async {
        center.getPendingNotificationRequests { (notifications) in
            for item in notifications {
                if let trigger = item.trigger as? UNCalendarNotificationTrigger,
                    let triggerDate = trigger.nextTriggerDate() {
                    var withSound = true
                    if(item.content.sound != UNNotificationSound.default)
                    {
                        withSound = false
                    }
                    self.reminders.append(Reminder(identifier: item.identifier, time: triggerDate, message: item.content.body, withSound: withSound, isAPendingNotification: true))
                }
            }

            self.remindersCount = notifications.count

            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                self.tableView.reloadData() // <---------
            }
        }
    }
}
```